# Practical or Best socket.io implementation

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

i have a problem over implementing sockets. Case:
the user has n number of rooms in his list, 
user should be able to receive notifications from each of the rooms.

method 1) open a socket for each room user has. in this user has to open multiple sockets for each room

method 2) users opens a single socket with room name = userid,
node maintains a list ('room_user') of each room and users in that room (this can be done on connection). 
eg

```
room_user:{ 
      room1 : {
             user1Id, user2Id
          }
      room2 : {
             user1Id, user3Id
          }
    }
```

For sending a message the server gets the userid's from the list for a specified room and then emits the message in a loop to all users. In this approach the user has to open only one socket but the server has to emit the same message in a loop

i want to know which method would be better suited

Comment: i am using socktio but i wanted to know should i open multiple socket for each room a user has or one socket per user

Comment: I think it would be better to maybe do a `namespace` per room and have each user have their own socket.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the underlaying TCP/IP broadcast system, you would probably find that it is better that the user have a single websocket connection and the server loop and send the same message again and again (method 2 in your question).

Allow me to explain:

TCP/IP doesn't support broadcasting. For this reason, sending the same message to multiple connections is actually implemented by looping over the list of connections and sending the same message again and again...

It's true that your code will be moving the loop to a higher level of the application, but it would probably be better than having many connections that would hinder your ability to scale the application.